# "URL Rewriting"/Routing with .net 3.0 and IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-6

I wonder what the best approach is for a situation where I want to have the user type in

http://myserver/something/20

and get redirected (301 or 302) to

http://someotherserver/applications/something/modules/default.aspx?id=20

For .net 3.5 and IIS 7 I found some solutions, but unfortunately I am stuck with .net 3.0 and IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003, and I do not want to install anything on the server if possible. I can change the settings for the Virtual Directory though, and if I have to for the entire site.

HTTPModules and web.config are ASP.net only If I am not completely mistaken, hence that will not help as /20 is not sent to ASP.net per Default?

Can anyone give me some tips where I can set up something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I have seen to do it without putting the 301 redirects directly into IIS Manager is to use Wildcard mapping

[Link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

You might enlist the assistance of ASP.

Create a 404.asp file in your something folder with the content:-

```
<%

Dim id : id = CLng(Mid(Request.QueryString, InStrRev(Request.QueryString, "/")+1))
Response.Redirect "http://someotherserver/applications/something/modules/default.aspx?   id=" & id

%>
```

In Custom errors of the something folder in IIS manager tweak to URL and /something/404.asp

Note the querystring value passed to the 404 customer error page looks like:-

404;http://myserver:80/something/20

**Edit:** D'oh or you could use a 404.ashx custom error page and then use more familiar .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

Map the `.*` extension to the same DLL as `.aspx` in the virtual directory's file mappings in Application Configuration. Then in the web.config's httpHandlers section, map the URL to the type.

Answer (score 1):

1. In IIS, right click on the **Virtual Directory**, select **Properties**.
2. Under the **Directory** tab, click the **Configuration...** button.
3. Under the **Mappings** tab, under the **Wildcard application maps** (order of implementation): click the **Insert...** button.
4. Browse and select **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll**, leave Verify that the file exists unchecked.
5. **Move Up** aspnet_isapi.dll to the top of the list.
6. Click **Ok, Ok**, and try it.  Try recycling the application pool if you don't see it work.

We had a situation where the .Net Routing was working on our development PCs but not on the test and production server with IIS 6 and Windows 2003.  This fixed our problem.